# How to enable automatic compilation in TeXiFy?

Tags: ide, texify-idea

I see there is support for automatic compilation(https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Automatic-compilation)

I followed the installation instructions and was able to compile something with no errors, but I can't find any mention of how to enable the automatic compilation.

I used the recommended pdf viewer (sumatraPDF) and as it says in the changelog for the update containing the feature on github I see the changed text highlighted in the editor so it seems that the only thing that I need to do is enable it.

I looked on the wiki for TexiFy and didn't understand what I should do (it seems that it should just be enabled by default but it's not).

Answer (score 2):

Go to **File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > TeXiFy** and check the checkbox in front of `Automatic compilation (warning: can cause high CPU usage)`. Then it is possible that you have to compile manually once before the automatic compilation takes over. However, do take into account the following warning from the wiki:

> In general, we advise against using this because once you are somewhat familiar with LaTeX there is no need to compile all the time to check if what you typed is correct, and compiling so much will have a serious impact on your CPU usage which can slow other things (including IntelliJ itself) down considerably.

You can probably guess from this warning that automatic compilation is **disabled** by default.